# accelerate framework can be imported to rubymotion project

Tags: ios7, fft, rubymotion, vdsp

`vDSP_create_fftsetup` called failed, here is the error:

> in 'pedometer_fft': undefined method 'vDSP_create_fftsetup' for # (NoMethodError).

but I have already imported in my rakefile, as below :

```
app.framework += %w(UIKit Foundation CFNetwork SystemConfiguration Accelerate )
```

and I use xcode version 5.1  in the same mac computer, it works well. So I don't think it is the version problem, did i miss something ? Why do other frameworks work well except accelerate framework in rubymotion?

Answer (score 0):

http://hipbyte.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/RM-173 it said it is a bug already fixed in version 2.7 , but i still cannot update to that version. so the problem is unsolved now.